# How to detect a hole in the triangular mesh?

Tags: algorithm, geometry

Actually, I can detect border or edges of a convex triangular mesh by checking which edge of the triangle does not have any neighbor. So, if a mesh has some holes, then we can highlight that part easily because we have edge vertices.

But the issue is, if we just have the edge vertices or borders, how can we know that the mesh has some holes ? and how many holes the mesh has ?

I thought enough about this issue, but unable to get it, any idea ? What should be the condition or check for hole detection ?

After detection of a hole I want to fill it. But first thing is to detect it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the mesh is connected and you can highlight all the boundaries. You are left with all the holes + one additional boundary which is that of mesh itself. You can just discard the boundary with the biggest length of them and get all the holes.

Comment: You can't guarantee that a hole has a smaller length than the enclosing mesh, unless the hole is convex.

Comment: actually the issue is this, when I detect boundary or borders vertices, all hole boundaries are also included in that because hole edges are also do not have any neighbors. So, the problem is to separate hole edges and mesh boundary ? How to know that these edges are from holes and remaining edges are from mesh boundary ?

Comment: That would require a scan of edges, and those which share a common vertex belong to a 'boundary' classifying which boundary is a hole is what i wrote in the answer. But there are a lot of corner cases here likr where the hole and the boundary shares a single vertex.

Comment: www.google.com/search?q=mesh+hole+filling seems to give some relevent paper citations.

Comment: Ok what do you mean by biggest length ? We just have vertices that lies on border ? How to detect close loop edges among them ? I am still unable to understand ? :)

Comment: Once you find all the edges which are 'boundary' edges, run them through a scan loop where you place first edge's vertices in a set, when you get the next edge check if the any of the vertices belong to the existing sets if not put them in a different set or if yes put them in the same set. After completetion you will have sets of vertices where each set will denote a boundary. Now just discard the set with biggest length And the remaining sets will be vertices of each hole they belong to.

Comment: @DanPuzey i am not sure if that holds becuase he states that the mesh is triangular. Can you give an example?

Comment: I think its really complicated. Let me spend some time on your comments, then I will let you know about my status. Thanks. :)

Comment: Mathematically you can construct an infinite number of meshes (e.g. based on cylinder shell or more complex geometries), where there are at 2 or more equally long boundaries. But for "normal" 3D scans, just using the longest boundary will perfectly do.

Answer (score 2):

A triangular mesh derived from a scanner (eg. Kinect) can have small fragments (isolated patches) as well as small holes. I suggest a hole can generally be detected by counting the number of vertices that neighbor the vertices on the boundary. It is not a hole if there are fewer neighboring vertices than boundary vertices.

Answer (score 0):

My answer will only work for a closed mesh, but it will handle the case of concave and convex holes.

For the sake of explanation, lets imagine a 2D mesh.

Calculate a bounding box for the mesh. In our example the bounding box needs to store min and max values for the X and Y axis, and a corresponding vertex index for each value:

```
struct BoundingBox
{
  float minX,maxX,minY,maxY;
  int vminX,vmaxX,vminY,vmaxY;
}
```

Iterate over every vertex in the mesh, growing the bounding box as you add each point. When a vertex is responsible for changing one of the min/max values, store or overwrite the corresponding vmin/vmax value with the vertex mesh index.

E.g.

```
BoundingBox bounds;
bounds.minX = verts[0].X;
bounds.maxX = verts[0].X;
bounds.minY = verts[0].Y;
bounds.maxY = verts[0].Y;
bounds.vminX = bounds.vmaxX = bounds.vminY = bounds.vmaxY = 0;
for (int i = 1; i < numVerts; i++)
{
  Vertex v = verts[i];
  if (v.X < bounds.minX) { bounds.minX = v.X; bounds.vminX = i; }
  if (v.X > bounds.maxX) { bounds.maxX = v.X; bounds.vmaxX = i; }
  if (v.Y < bounds.minY) { bounds.minY = v.Y; bounds.vminY = i; }
  if (v.Y > bounds.maxY) { bounds.maxY = v.Y; bounds.vmaxY = i; }
}
```

Now iterate over your boundaries until you find one which contains ALL the vertices you gathered in the bounding box. This is your outer boundary. The remaining boundaries are holes within the mesh.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, a hole in triangular mesh is a closed loop of adjacent oriented boundary edges, each of which does not have a triangle from one side (e.g. from left).

So the algorithm to enumerate all holes can be as follows

1. Find all boundary edges (the edges without left triangle) and compose a set with them.
2. Take any boundary edge from the set, then search for the next edge in the set originating in the vertex where the previous edge terminates, remove it from the set as well and continue until edge loop is closed. This will give you one of the holes.
3. Repeat step 2. until the set is empty.

Some operations here can be optimized by using specialized data structures for mesh representation, e.g. [half-edges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_connected_edge_list).

The animation below demonstrates how starting from an arbitrary boundary edge (under the cursor), the whole hole can be found and highlighted:

[image]

(captured in [MeshInspector](https://github.com/MeshInspector/MeshInspector) application)